# Extract CLOB JSON data into local variables in Oracle

Tags: json, oracle, web-services, plsql, clob

I am getting a JSON response from a web service. I want to extract that JSON data into a PL/SQL variables. Can u please explain how can I acheive that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of Oracle? 12c has native JSON handling. In earlier versions your can try [PL/JSON](https://github.com/pljson/pljson/).

Comment: I'm using 12c version. Can't use PL/JSON or APEX due to requirements. How can I achieve from PL/SQL without any libraries?

Comment: If you're on 12c then use the built-in [JSON handling](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/json.htm#ADXDB6246), as Hawk already linked to in their answer.

Answer (score 0):

As Alex Poole mentioned in the comment, if you are using [Oracle 12c](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/json.htm), then you'll have rich functionalities supporting creating and reading JSON. Even if you are running on earlier version, and have Oracle APEX 5.0 or above installed (if not, you can install it, it is free), then you can take advantage of the rich [APEX_JSON](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39149/apex_json.htm#AEAPI29635) package and what it offers of similar functionalities.

However, if both options are not available for you, then you can resort to [PL/SQL](https://github.com/pljson/pljson/) suite of packages. Below is a simple snippet to show you how to use them after you install them.

```
DECLARE
  l_param_list     VARCHAR2(512);

  l_http_request   UTL_HTTP.req;
  l_http_response  UTL_HTTP.resp;

  l_response_text  VARCHAR2(32767);

l_list json_list; --json array type
A_id           VARCHAR2(200);
UserId         VARCHAR2(100);
UserName       VARCHAR2(100);
OutletCode     VARCHAR2(100);
OutletName     VARCHAR2(100);
MobileNumber   VARCHAR2(100);
PhoneNumber    VARCHAR2(100);
Address        VARCHAR2(100);
City           VARCHAR2(100);
State          VARCHAR2(100);
Postcode       VARCHAR2(100);
Email          VARCHAR2(100);
UpdateCount    VARCHAR2(100);
loginCount     VARCHAR2(100);
ReferencePhoto VARCHAR2(100);
Updates        VARCHAR2(100);
AccountLocked  VARCHAR2(100);
Oracle_Flag    VARCHAR2(100);
acl            VARCHAR2(100);

BEGIN  
   -- preparing Request...
  l_http_request := UTL_HTTP.begin_request('/*your GET service URL here*/'
                                      , 'GET'
                                      , 'HTTP/1.1');

  -- ...set header's attributes
  UTL_HTTP.set_header(l_http_request, '/*header name*/', '/*header value*/');

  -- ...set input parameters
  -- UTL_HTTP.write_text(l_http_request, l_param_list);

  -- get Response and obtain received value
  l_http_response := UTL_HTTP.get_response(l_http_request);

  UTL_HTTP.read_text(l_http_response, l_response_text);

  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(l_response_text);
  l_list := json_list(l_response_text); -- get json response here

--loop through JSON response array:
FOR i IN 1..l_list.count
LOOP
  A_id           := json_ext.get_string(json(l_list.get(i)),'_id');
  UserId         := json_ext.get_string(json(l_list.get(i)),'UserId');
  UserName       := json_ext.get_string(json(l_list.get(i)),'UserName');
  OutletCode     := json_ext.get_string(json(l_list.get(i)),'OutletCode');
  OutletName     := json_ext.get_string(json(l_list.get(i)),'OutletName');
  MobileNumber   := json_ext.get_string(json(l_list.get(i)),'MobileNumber');
  PhoneNumber    := json_ext.get_string(json(l_list.get(i)),'PhoneNumber');
  Address        := json_ext.get_string(json(l_list.get(i)),'Address');
  City           := json_ext.get_string(json(l_list.get(i)),'City');
  State          := json_ext.get_string(json(l_list.get(i)),'State');
  Postcode       := json_ext.get_string(json(l_list.get(i)),'Postcode');
  Email          := json_ext.get_string(json(l_list.get(i)),'Email');
  UpdateCount    := json_ext.get_string(json(l_list.get(i)),'UpdateCount');
  loginCount     := json_ext.get_string(json(l_list.get(i)),'loginCount');
  ReferencePhoto := json_ext.get_string(json(l_list.get(i)),'ReferencePhoto');
  Updates        := json_ext.get_string(json(l_list.get(i)),'Updates');
  AccountLocked  := json_ext.get_string(json(l_list.get(i)),'AccountLocked');
  Oracle_Flag    := json_ext.get_string(json(l_list.get(i)),'Oracle_Flag');
  acl            := json_ext.get_string(json(l_list.get(i)),'acl');

--insert into your table
insert .....
```

Comment: I'm aware of both the tools. But I can't either install APEX or PL/JSON as I can't install them in production. I have to achieve this from native PL/SQL code only. And I'm using 12c database version.